# Sticky footer + floating elements

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

One more question about the sticky footer css...
lets say i have the following markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="body">body</div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

As you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LaDmh/), with the given css, sticky footer works like a charm.
It stays at the bottom of the page if div#body has only a few contents, and is pushed out of screen at the bottom when there are lots of contents.

My problem now is when i try to put 2 floating divs(1 left - 1 right) in the div#body.
Then the footer is at the bottom of the screen but is not pushed down when there are a lot of contents (You can see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9FwCN/))

How can i make make it work? i've tried 1000 tricks found on the web, still not able to understand how to make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
#body {
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

EDIT: This way you won't need an extra element to clear the floats.

Comment: Here's a working example of this same solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20114486/618649

Answer (score 4):

Put `<br style="clear:both;" />` after your floating divs.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9FwCN/1/

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, it really works. Per Holmäng'suggestion also works but he was a bit faster, so i'll accept his answer. But thanks again for bothering! :)

Comment: The only unfortunate thing about a solution like this one is that it puts layout logic into what should only be data (HTML = data, CSS = layout).